# Interoperate Activity with AsyncTask

Tags: android

Are there any relative order constraints between an `Activity`'s lifecycle callbacks and an `AsyncTask`'s callbacks?

(For example, between `onCreate` and `onPostExecute`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two should be totally independent. You can use an AsyncTask without an activity, for example in a service.

When you use an AsyncTask in an Activity, the Activity could be paused because another activity is shown to the user, but your `AsyncTask` could continue working in the background.